# Reoccuring SSLEOFError handling

Tags: python, ssl, error-handling, apple-push-notifications, web.py

I have a python server using web.py that communications with Apple Push Notification Servers which is experiencing an SSLEOFError fairly often. I've tried to handle this error, but I can't seem to find it in the ssl module or pyopenssl or _ssl. Any help in handling this error or possibly preventing it would be greatly appreciated. Here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/API/api.py", line 189, in GET
    COMMAND_QUEUE.get_queue(sql)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/queue.py", line 165, in get_queue
    self.send_apns(row['udid'], sql)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/queue.py", line 219, in send_apns
    except ssl.SSLEOFError:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SSLEOFError'
```

EDIT: Here's the stack trace without bad error handling. I now realize that I should probably be handling just the super class `ssl.SSLERROR` instead of `ssl.SSLEOFERROR` and I'm going to try that, but any insight into why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

```
Unexpected error: <class 'ssl.SSLError'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/API/api.py", line 189, in GET
    COMMAND_QUEUE.get_queue(sql)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/queue.py", line 165, in get_queue
    self.send_apns(row['udid'], sql)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mdm-server/server/queue.py", line 216, in send_apns
    wrapper.notify()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APNSWrapper-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/APNSWrapper/notifications.py", line 194, in notify
    apnsConnection.connect(apnsHost, self.apnsPort)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APNSWrapper-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 215, in connect
    self.context().connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APNSWrapper-0.6.1-py2.7.egg/APNSWrapper/connection.py", line 161, in connect
    self.connectionContext.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 433, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 423, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Edit2: ssl.SSLError handles the error.

Edit3: I did have to edit APNSWrapper to use TLSv1 as detailed in this GitHub repository, in the Server Setup section. [Example iOS MDM Server](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured this out. APNSWrapper throws this error when the APNs server can't communicate with the intended phone. (I.E. the phone is off or has no reception.) In case anyone else runs into this issue, a try/except block catching `ssl.SSLError` will handle this exception. It would probably be a good idea to hold off on another call to APNs for a bit if this is the case.